# $f$ unbounded in $\mathbb{R}$ implies it cannot be in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Intuitively , I feel this must be true. I'm looking for a rigorous proof. So,I would like to confirm that there are no counter examples to begin with.

Comment: Do you mean unbounded almost everywhere?

Comment: What I mean is: there is no $ K $ such that $f(x) < K$ for all $x$.

Comment: @DanZimm I'm not able to get what is meant by 'unbounded almost everywhere'. What I think it means is that: the set of points where it is bounded is measure zero.Is this not the same as saying it is unbounded ?  Thank you.

Comment: So unbounded almost everywhere would mean the set $\{x \mid f(x) \le K \}$ is of measure $0$. So for example $f(x) = x \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is unbounded, but $f(x)$ isn't unbounded almost everywhere (because it's bounded almost everywhere, which is in some sense the exact opposite).

Comment: @DanZimm So as explained by user71352 if $f$ is unbounded almost everywhere (which implies that it is unbounded on a set of positive measure ) it cannot be in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: Note that unbounded a.e. means **for any $K$** the set $\{ x \mid f(x) \le K \}$ is of measure $0$. This I believe then would imply it cannot be in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. This unbounded a.e., however is a much stronger statement than just unbounded. In other words unbounded a.e. means the set which it is ever bounded is measure $0$ (i.e. very small). A function like this is very bad. Note that talking about $f$ being unbounded on a positive measure means saying $\{ x \mid f(x) > K \}$ for every $K$ which implies $f(x) = \infty$ on this set, so again this function is very bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's wrong. Define
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-1/3} & x \in (0,1)\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is unbounded, but 
$$ \int_0^1 f^2(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 x^{-2/3}\, dx = 3 $$

---

Addendum: 
To give another example, that shows that even if $f$ is bounded on compact sets, it can be unbounded, but still be $L^2$. Let 
$$ f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot \chi_{[n,n+n^{-4})}$$
where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$. Then $f$ is unbounded, but bounded on compact sets and 
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} f^2(x)\, dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+n^{-4}} n^2 \,dx 
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^2} < \infty $$

Comment: Thank you.Can you suggest a good reference for studying Lp spaces ? Especially I would like to learn about the type of functions similar to the second example you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

martini has answered your question quite thoroughly but just for fun note that $f$ could be unbounded in every open interval inside $(0,1)$ but yet still be in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Consider $f(x)=q$ if $x\in(0,1)$ and $x=\frac{p}{q}$, $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $f=0$ almost everwhere and hence integrates to $0$. By shifting the previous function you can get a function that is unbounded in every open interval but integrates to $0$.

Comment: Do you mean to say $p \in \mathbb{N}$ as well?

Comment: I do but it isn't useful in this case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hrm without specifying that $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ you could have $p$ be any real number in $(0,1)$ and then $q=1$ so that $f(x)=1$ for every $x$, so you need that constraint right?

Comment: Good point. My apologies.

Comment: No problem, I've done similar things several times ;D

Comment: @user71352 Thank you for the example.In the answers we have considered functions unbounded on a set of measure 0. Can we prove this if it is unbounded on a set of positive measure ?

Comment: It is not possible to be $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ and be unbounded on a set of positive measure. To see this consider sets of the form $\{x\vert\lvert f(x)\rvert\ge N\}$.